# External Hard Drive not Recognized by Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive

So I'm trying to get an external hard drive working.  I am running Windows 7 Ultimate.  It's a WD Black 2.5 inch 750 GB drive inside a Sabrent external HD case.  The drive is recognized by the BIOS and by Device Manager, but is not viewable from My Computer.

Obviously, the issue is that there isn't a drive letter assigned.  I went into Computer Management and tried to assign a letter, but the option to do so is greyed out.

If possible, I would like to view and hopefully recover the 50GB of data currently on the drive instead of having to just wipe it out.

Any ideas?

[EDIT] I figured out a way to get the information off the drive, but I still can't make my Windows computer recognize it.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up finding a solution.  I booted my computer into Linux, after which the drives were recognized and letters were assigned.  I recovered all the data, then used Linux to reformat the drive.  I booted back into Windows 7, and the drive was clean and a letter was assigned.

Answer (score -1):

There are numerous file systems (FAT FAT32 exFAT NTFS ext4 ...) used by various OSs (macOS Windows Linux ...), some of which can be accessed by certain OSs and others that can be accessed by other OSs. Windows has built-in capabilities for read/writing a handful of file systems and there are third party programs that enable other file systems to be read/write. Some file systems cannot be read by Windows.

Also, broadly speaking, if the drive is larger than 2TB some computers running some versions of Windows won't be able to access those drives without special third party drivers.

If you have recovered the data, why not just format the drive in Windows using a file system that is designed for Windows (FAT32 NTFS exFAT ...)?